# Film where clowns are a separate species hunted by humans

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the last few years, I saw a trailer for a film where clowns are a separate species that are hunted by humans (or at least by the people shown in the film). I remember it largely being by guys in pickup trucks, carrying hunting rifles. For some reason, I remember one of them shooting from a ladder in the bed of the pickup truck. In other parts of the film, they're luring the clowns using things like cream pies and floppy shoes.

I think I saw the trailer on Youtube around the same time I saw the one for [*ClownTown*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4577344/), which was released in 2016, which suggests I may have seen the trailer around 2015, although the film may be older.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently I was using the wrong search terms. I was using something like *film hunting clowns*, which brought up films about killer clowns, when I should have been using *film "hunting clowns"*. That brought up [this 2007 article about a then-upcoming movie](https://blog.mysanantonio.com/weekender/2007/06/robert-earl-keen-to-star-in-film-about-hunting-clowns-daily-clips-on-youtube/) entitled [*Clownhunt*](http://www.clownhunt.com/).

> Keen, a prankster with a clever sense of humor if there ever was one, will be among the actors in “Clown Hunt,” which began filming today in Snyder, a little west of Abilene.
>
> It’s a satire about a group of hunters tracking clowns during the annual clown hunting season, according to a press release.

....

> The clip goes into a few hunting methods, too. When walking and stalking plays out, the hunters turn to bait. Not corn — rather, colorful balloons tied to a tree at the brush line.
>
> The hunters retreat to a field to hide.
>
> While they wait, one uses a clown call, much like a duck call. Except this one is a bulb horn clowns are so well known for (think Harpo Marx).

This may have been the trailer I saw:

Comment: Wait... You mean that's not how it is now? I had my clown tags and everything! ;-)